# What is section ".debug_info" in an elf file?

Tags: c++, elf, map-files

I have an elf file, while analysing the mapfile and elf using elfparser, I saw a section called .Debug_info, which is taking largest memory.

I am compiling for xtensa DSP, using xt-xc++, I haven't used -g option also given -o2 optimization level.

[image]

is it possible to remove this for release builds?

Comment: Don't know that compiler but does it matter? There usually is a kind of objcopy post build step to create the programmer specific binary anyway which should discard those sections.

Comment: Have you tried using `-g0`? Or adding `--gc-sections` parameter to `ld`? Anyway,  it's usually done by `-s` command or `strip` tool.

Comment: @DanM., -g0 and -s option didn't work.

Comment: @thomachan missed that you use custom xtensa compiler. When try just running strip (or xt-strip?) on your final binary.

Comment: I can not use strip because it removes completesymbol tables. I need to use nm command on this binary.

Comment: Have you already seen this?: [How debuggers work: Part 3 - Debugging information](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/02/07/how-debuggers-work-part-3-debugging-information).

Comment: @thomachan Read the man page for `strip`. It has all kinds of options that allow you to decide what to strip, including stripping only debug information.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> section called `.debug_info`, which is taking largest memory.

Note that this section does not have `SHF_ALLOC` flag, and therefore does *not* take any RAM at runtime (it only takes space in the filesystem). Of course if you use ramdisk, then that section still does cost you RAM in the end.

> is it possible to remove this for release builds?

Yes: none of the `.debug*` sections are necessary at runtime, and all of them can be safely stripped.

> `-g0` and `-s` option didn't work.

It's likely that you are getting `.debug_*` sections from libraries that you are linking in, and not from your own code. The `-g` was present when the libraries were compiled, so building with `-g0` doesn't have any effect.

It's surprising that `-s` didn't work, but maybe your compiler interprets this flag differently.

In any case, you should use `strip --strip-debug` to get rid of `.debug_*` sections (note: this does *not* remove the symbol table).

The best practice is actually to compile all your code with full debug info (`-g`), save the full debug binary for post-mortem analysis, use `strip --strip-debug` to make a release binary, and use that binary for actual distribution.

If/when the release binary crashes and leaves a core dump, having (saved) full-debug exactly matching binary greatly improves post-mortem analysis you can do.